# I can type with the image inserter open

Tags: discussion, support, uploader

Steps to repro:

1. Open a new post
2. Open the image inserter (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>)
3. Type - the typed text will appear
4. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> - the text will go.
5. Open the inserter again
6. Type - again the text will appear
7. Click outside the uploaded to close it - the text will stay.

Is this intended behaviour?

Comment: Well, when you *close* the editor, anything you typed while it was open gets removed... I just thought that was humorous. Don't know why it happens.

Comment: @animuson it's removed only when pressing ESC, if I just click outside nothing is removed.